# App crashing on opening QR Scanner Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am using `QR Scanner` to scan a `qr code` but when I click on scan qr button the app is crashing. 
**This is my code:**

```
  Future scanQR() async {
    String barcode = await scanner.scan();
    setState(() => this.barcode = barcode);
    print(barcode);
  }
```

I am using this plugin for qr scanner:

https://pub.dev/packages/qrscan#-installing-tab-

I am not getting any errors in logs as well

Comment: could you post error log?

Comment: @Mahendra I am not any errors

Comment: Yow bro make sure you added the permissions to use the camera in your android.xml and info.plist even though the documentation didn't say so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue by using a different plugin

`import 'package:flutter_barcode_scanner/flutter_barcode_scanner.dart';`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the permissions needed in android an in IOS?

Comment: Yes I have added

Comment: since you did not provide any logs even though it's not showing any errors do you mind switching to another plugin? try using https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner